# How Facebook generate unique identifiers

Tags: algorithm, encryption, unique

I am looking for the way for generating unique identifiers for different business entities in project I am working on. Currently we are using GUIDs, but we want to move to number identifiers. I have worked with Facebook Graph API and figured out they have some kind of *unique* and *self-contained* (as I supposed) ids. But I could not find any information or assumptions in the Internet about how they generate this keys.

I formulated some minimum requirments for identifiers based on my suggestions and investigation of Facebook ids. Here they are:

- It must be presented as `long` / `Int64` value.
- It must be unique in scope of whole system.
- It must contains as minimum type of requesting entity (user, page, etc.). So that it gives possibility to create сonvenient API like `GET {host}/{id}`.

Does anybody have any experience or ideas how can this task can be solved? I guess there should be some existing solutions or specifications for it. If anybody has some suggestions it would be great to hear that.

Comment: What's wrong with GUIDs?

Comment: @ThrowingSpoon you are not able to put some required information I mentioned above inside of GUID during generation.

Comment: you want to put some information in your uid? like use it as an encrypted string? A good random generator should not require any input.

Comment: @AyonNahiyan I didn't mention _random_ in my list of requirments :) sure it can have some random segment inside which ensures key is unique, but I am not looking for random generator.

Comment: (1) Asking how some part of Facebook works is off topic for [so]. (2) (a) If your only requirement is uniqueness, you can just have an auto-incrementing value. (b) If you want something less predictable, I'm sure mathematical functions exist which iterate over all possible input in a non-linear manner. (c) If you want something actually random, you'll need to keep track of all IDs generated thus far to avoid duplicates. (3) You may want to narrow down the scope of this question (although I'm sure you can find plenty of posts on generating unique IDs).

Comment: "It must contains as minimum type of requesting entity" - if you mean the requesting entity must be encoded in the ID, a simple way to achieve that is to assign a few of the bits to store that information (e.g. 000... = user, 001... = page, 010... = ...).

Comment: @Dukeling I am not asking directly how they do it, actually. I am just looking for some close solutions meeting the same requirments as minimum. The Facebook is just an example in my question giving a possibility to get what I mean.

Comment: @Dukeling (2) (a) No, it is not my only one requirment. And I am not searching less predictable id generation mechanism (b). Probably I was not so clear, sorry for that in this case. I need some kind of tool which provides me possibility based on id to determine what kind of entity the clients is going to request. As I see it right now, it is quite good idea to assign a few bits, I will investigate and look through possibilities, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the answer for me was Twitter Snowflake. Also you can find some interesting useful information here: [Sharding & IDs at Instagram](https://engineering.instagram.com/sharding-ids-at-instagram-1cf5a71e5a5c). Hope it helps somebody.